# Why can i assign clear out-of-range values to a TypeScript enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

Why is this piece of TypeScript code allowed:

```
const enum Foobar {
    Foo = 0,
    Bar = 1
}

let a: Foobar = 42;
const b: 42 = 42;
a = b;
```

I understand that enums *can* be dynamic. But I feel like this example should not be allowed using the TypeScript control flow analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is allowed because TS doesn't distinguish between bitflag and non-bitflag enums.

Out-of-range values commonly occur with bitflag enums:

```
const enum Foobar {
  Foo = 0,
  Bar = 1,
  Baz = 2,
  Qoo = 4
}

let a: Foobar = Foobar.Qoo | Foobar.Baz;
```

Here, `a` clearly has the value 6, but this isn't an obvious violation of the intent of the enum.

Comment: So it's comparable in functionality to a `[Flags]` enum in C#? Thanks for your answer. We'll use it in our TypeScript course material :+1: